# Getting CdbExcpetion

Tags: yii

i have sql query which is working fine in my core php project. but in yii i am trying to execute same query in controller. but i am getting this error.

**CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access

   violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''2013-09-10')' at line 1. The 
   SQL statement executed was: insert into members_95 (exercise_type,exercise,reps,date) 
   values ('Circuit','',,'2013-09-10')**

i don't know why yii generating Exception for this?

Comment: try: insert into members_95 (exercise_type,exercise,reps,date) values ('Circuit','',null,'2013-09-10')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here your query contains 4 attributes and you are giving value only 3.

so you can change your query like this...

```
insert into members_95 (exercise_type,exercise,reps,date) values ('Circuit','','','2013-09-10')
```

or else make 3rd field as **varchar** instead of **int**. by doing this by default it will take null value like how it's taking for null (' ') value for your 2nd field.